# Spring-Boot Properties with nested Map

Tags: spring-boot, dictionary, properties

I have a `application.properties` file that needs some dynamic keys, which allow at least one level of nesting. In technical terms, the application starts and I am able to read those values, but the metadata doesn't seem to work correctly, because IntelliJ Ultimate is giving me some errors:
`Cannot resolve property 'foo' in java.util.Map`

```
# Static property
com.company.version=1.0

# Dynamic property, starting after products
com.company.products.first.foo=firstFoo
com.company.products.first.bar=firstBar
com.company.products.second.foo=SecondFoo
```

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.company")
public class Properties {
    private String version;
    private Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> products = new HashMap<>();

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

In additional I would like to know what the best practice would be to read those values. For "normal" static properties I used the `Environment` that I autowire in the constructor, but that is – as far as I know – unable to read the products map. Thats why I autowire my `Properties` class and use the `getProducts` function.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Might this work?

```
# Dynamic property, starting after products
com.company.products.first[foo]=firstFoo
com.company.products.first[bar]=firstBar
com.company.products.second[foo]=SecondFoo
```

If you want more than item in your array list do:

```
com.company.products.first[foo]=firstFoo,secondFoo
```

However, I've come massively unstuck in the past using deeply nested maps of maps. Maybe if you can declare a concrete class instead?
Also, I'd suggest using interfaces rather than concrete collections (e.g. List rather than ArrayList, or maybe even a Set to prevent duplicates?)